# Slave Kerberos behind NAT - kprop fails: Incorrect net address while decoding database size from client

Tags: kerberos, mitkerberos

I want to synchronize MIT Kerberos database from master to slave, which is in a different geographical location. kprop synchronization fails because of a NAT. Is there any solution to have kprop working? Except VPN and manual database copy with SSH.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I see is to copy DB manually from master server:

```
kdb5_util dump /etc/krb5kdc/slave_datatrans
scp /etc/krb5kdc/slave_datatrans root@slave.host:/etc/krb5kdc/slave_datatrans
ssh root@slave.host 'kdb5_util load /etc/krb5kdc/slave_datatrans; rm /etc/krb5kdc/slave_datatrans;'
rm /etc/krb5kdc/slave_datatrans*
```